# external directory list and download

Tags: php, directory, download

I am trying to make a script that will let me download files outside my web root directory and list the files...It is listing the files of the directory but it does not allow me to download them as when they are clicked it just goes to website.com/clickedlink.jpg but it needs to some how change that to go to the location I would like...

I think I am explaining this a little odd so please tell me if it needs clarification.

I need to download files from /home/files/I/need but the website is stored in /var/website/

so if someone could please help out I'd be 100% thankful!

```
<html><head><title>Root page</title></head><body>


<? 
// open this directory 
$myDirectory = opendir("/home/files/I/need");

// get each entry
while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
    $dirArray[] = $entryName;
}

// close directory
closedir($myDirectory);

//  count elements in array
$indexCount = count($dirArray);
Print ("$indexCount files<br>\n");

// sort 'em
sort($dirArray);

// print 'em
print("<TABLE border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0 class=whitelinks>\n");
print("<TR><TH>Filename</TH><th>Filetype</th><th>Filesize</th></TR>\n");
// loop through the array of files and print them all
for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
        if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != "."){ // don't list hidden files
        print("<TR><TD><a href=\"$dirArray[$index]\">$dirArray[$index]</a></td>");
        print("<td>");
        print(filetype($dirArray[$index]));
        print("</td>");
        print("<td>");
        print(filesize($dirArray[$index]));
        print("</td>");
        print("</TR>\n");
    }
}
print("</TABLE>\n");
?>
</body></html>


</body></html>
```

Comment: You can create symlink, folder/location alias or using absolute path with files.

Comment: I did try something like that...and I think I did it but it doesn't work....
I made a folder called downloads in my webroot and tried to use symlink to connect it to the other folder...and I think it worked cause in my ftp client when I click the download folder in web root it directs me to the other folder, however when I click the link to download I get a not found error

Comment: you need to create alias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to let your web server take care of this by creating a location alias; having the web server perform the downloading for you is much more scalable than doing this in PHP.

However, since you asked for a PHP solution, add this to this top of your script:

```
$basePath = "/home/files/I/need";
if (isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) && $file = basename($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])) {
    if (file_exists("$basePath/$file")) {
        // add file size
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize("$basePath/$file"));
        // write file to output
        readfile("$basePath/$file");
        return;
    }
}
```

To construct the URL to make the download:

```
/path/to/your/script.php/clickedlink.jpg
```

The `/path/to/your/script.php` is the same URL that generates the page; you append a slash, together with the intended filename.

I'm using `basename()` to prevent people from accessing `../../../etc/passwd` or some other file they shouldn't be seeing, but that also means you can't use sub folders. If you need to support sub folders, you have to sanitize the `PATH_INFO` in a different manner.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what I should do... I add that to the top of my script and modify what?

Comment: @Butterflycode the code I posted basically takes care of the download itself ... you just append `/clickedlink.jpg` behind the URL and that should work

Comment: That works, pretty well, one issue is it's not like a normal download, when it starts downloading it doesn't say how big it is it just keeps going until it is downloaded...is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I wouldn't mind adding folders within the folder I am downloading from, if it's simple to do, would you be able to share it?

Comment: @Butterflycode you just have to make sure to strip leading slashes and periods from `PATH_INFO`.

Comment: @Butterflycode `preg_replace('#^[./]+#', '', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);`

Comment: I placed that on top of the script and it doesn't work as far as I can tell, it just trys to download the folder as a file.

Comment: The script expects to download a file, not a folder. That's a whole different story lol

Comment: I don't want it to download a folder! I want it when the folder is clicked to go inside and allow downloading of the files inside the folder much like the root folder

Comment: @Butterflycode well, you can use `is_dir` to find out if the selection is a folder and then update your `$myDirectory`; then the script would show the folder contents? Does that make sense?